# Clear the selected value in dropdown_button2 flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using [dropdown_button2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) for dropdown feature.How to clear the value in this dropdown when close the screen.?

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                child: DropdownButton2<CategoryList>(
                                  hint: Text(
                                    'Select Item',
                                    style: GoogleFonts.inter(
                                      fontSize: 13,

                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  items:  collectionController. libContentGetResponse2.value.data!.rows!
                                      .map((item) =>
                                      DropdownMenuItem<CategoryList>(
                                        value: item,
                                        child: Text(
                                          item.categoryName.toString(),
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 14,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ))
                                      .toList(),
                                  value: getSelected(),
                                  onChanged: (CategoryList? value) {

                                    collectionController.selectItem.value  = value!;
    

                                  },
                               
                                  dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
                                  buttonWidth: MediaQuery.of(conText).size.width / 2.7,
                                  buttonPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
                                  buttonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius:  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                                    border: Border.all(color: Color(0xffD9D9D9),width: 1),

                                  ),
                                ),
                              )


      CategoryList? getSelected() {
        if (collectionController.selectItem.value == null) return null;
        try {
          var selectedIndex = collectionController. libContentGetResponse2.value.data!.rows!
              .indexWhere((element) => element.categoryName == collectionController.selectItem.value .categoryName);
          if (selectedIndex != -1)
            return collectionController. libContentGetResponse2.value.data!.rows![selectedIndex];
          else
            return null;
        } catch (e) {
          return null;
        }
      }
```

Now my CategoryList has two values ["A", "B"]. I selected A and navigated to another screen then again opened the screen which has this dropdown button. Instead of showing the hint, the previously selected item is displayed there.